# Unable to install Net::LDAP for Strawberry Perl on Windows

Tags: windows, perl, makefile, bugzilla, strawberry-perl

I have downloaded and installed Strawberry Perl on a Windows 2012 R2 server to run Bugzilla. I have everything installed and configured fine, and Bugzilla is running, but I have a requirement to use LDAP integration. So I tried to install the `Net::LDAP` module using `perl install-module Net::LDAP`, but it fails to install because it needs `GSSAPI` which requires `krb5_config`.

After working with the people at Bugzilla, I have installed the MIT Kerberos for Windows with the SDK, and ran `perl install-module GSSAPI --shell` to get to CPAN. Then I ran `look GSSAPI` so I could download everything and try making the file, but this is where it is failing. I can't figure out what command to run next. I tried `MakeFile.pl --gssapi_inc` as well as `MakeFile.pl --gssapi_libs`, but both give me this error:

> run "perl Makefile.PL --help" to see further installation options if options gssapi_libs or gssapi_lddlflags are provided, then gssapi_inc must be as well at C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\build\GSSAPI-0.28-JPLEEE\Makefile.PL line 89.

I am now completely lost as to what I need to do to install the `Net::LDAP` module.

Note: I am using Strawberry Perl and not ActiveState perl so installing via PPM is not an option.

Second NOTE: I know this might be off topic for Stackoverflow but as it does relate to programming I thought it might fit here, if it is a better fit somewhere else please just flag to move.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, Strawberry Perl does come with the PPM module installed, so you can use ppm to install modules.  Personally, I have never used ppm to install modules with Strawberry Perl.

To install a module, you just type 'cpan install [module]'.  So for the Net::LDAP module, that command becomes:  cpan install Net::LDAP

I just tried to install Net::LDAP using portable Strawberry Perl 5.22.1.2 32-bit on Windows 8 and it installed without any issues.

I do not have the MIT Kerberos installed, but I also tried to install the GSSAPI module and that failed.  Part of the output from that attempt showed Linux paths.  And the CPAN Testers matrix for that module does not show any tests done on Windows.  It's possible that you don't really need to have that module installed and might not be able to install that module on Windows.